# Safari ignores onChange on file input, when triggered from a ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, safari, ref

I have a file upload, and I want to replace the native one with a nicer React component.

The whole upload is a component that repeats 3 times. It works on all 3 instances in Chrome but in Safari only on the last 2.

This is how it looks on safari: https://share.getcloudapp.com/9ZuYmyrd

```
const inputEl = useRef(null)

const onButtonClick = () => {
  inputEl.current.click()
}

// ...
<CardActions className={c.actions}>
  <input
    id='upload-file'
    className={c.fileInput}
    type='file'
    accept='image/*'
    onChange={handleChange}
    ref={inputEl}
  />

  <label className={c.label} htmlFor="upload-file">
    <Fab
      onClick={onButtonClick}
      color="default"
      className={c.addPicture}
    >
      <AddIcon/>
    </Fab>
  </label>
</CardActions>
```

Whan I switch to the native input, all works fine